# Any reason a QGraphicsItem.setRotation could ever go wrong?

Tags: qt, pyqt, qt5, qgraphicsitem

[MINIMISED code provided for example and question EDITED]

I have subscribed here to ask what seems like a simple question (see title, and more descr. below) but comes from hours of bug tracing all the way down to the normally most harmless method, and several minutes of awe wondering what could technically be happening.

**Context**

Two QGraphicsView+Scene pairs in different windows and a simple QGraphicsItem hierarchy.

**Problem**

Application freezes on either setRotation given in example.

A minimal file set is pushed to the "debug" branch of the [Git repos](https://sourceforge.net/p/atc-pie/code/ci/debug/tree/) so you can download the snapshot and experience the problem. [Serious downsizing effort :-p  "173 files changed, 356 insertions(+), 2763256 deletions(-)"]

**Remarks**

- If you comment out both setRotation lines (66 and 95, marked with "#FIXME") in the GUI.graphics.contact module, you get a running program where you can wheel in/out and pan the scene with no trouble.
- The freeze also disappears if you comment out the new window creation (line 17 in GUI.main).
- No freeze if the items are out of the view.

**Tried solving**

- Moving the setRotation outside of the paint method and setting from the parentItem, but still freezes, therefore not a problem of calling from the paint method.
- QMutexing the setRotations did not change anything (in despair you try funny things!)

**The question**

Of course you may simply know exactly what I should do with my program, but if not I would like to address the simple question: provided I have typed 'x' float and being as creative as you can, what could possibly make a .setRotation(x) call to freeze a program?

Thanks to you.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please note that few people are likely to want to download and trawl through your whole project in order to assist you. I suggest you read [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) which recommends you **Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem** and [How to Create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Then, edit your question appropriately.

Comment: It had taken me so much time to accuse the least suspicious methods of all that I could not feel like doing it at the time. I rather hoped I would get an answer to the "simple" question, providing the code only to the hardcore testers. But I built up courage this morning and here it is. You can download the new snapshot which is only a few files this time. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

(Since there has been no discussion here and the answer came from elsewhere, would it just be better to delete the question? In any case here it is, people may be watching this thread.)

The answer can be found [here](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/63358-Application-freeze-on-QGraphicsItem-setRotation).